# Extending cURL max URL length or other options?

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending a rather long URL with cURL and I'm almost positive that it's too long for cURL to handle.  The URL is `http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=` and after the `?player=` paramter, there can be up to 12 numbers/letters/symbols.

Is there an alternative to cURL which would support long URLs like that, or could I use cURL with that long of a URL somehow?

Comment: 62 characters not too long for curl. The [curl homepage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/features.html) says "no length limit" in fact.

Comment: I frequently use cURL with longer URLs than that. Perhaps if you edit your question to include the error you're seeing we can help you out better.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error, but when I asked a previous question [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019661/mass-inserting-into-an-mysql-database-via-php-skips-names), someone replied that it was too long.  The above link is my problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

symbols could be the possible cause
use some thing like

[urlencode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

[base64-encode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

function getStats($username) { echo $username // to see if username is being sent to this function

just run this code as a standalone to see if it works

```
function getStats($username) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = array('player' => '$username');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($ch);
}

getStats('what_ever_username');
```

Comment: The only symbol that would be used is `_` so that wouldn't really matter, would it?

Comment: _ should not matter but you did say symbols. could you post an example of this varible.

Comment: It works fine if I just do one name, but I'm reading from a textarea (multiple names, separated by line) and then sending the names via a POST field, then grabbing it using this: `$names = explode("\r\n", $_POST['names']);`.  I seem to only get the problem with names that are 12 characters (the max length of a name).

Comment: When using that method I get `404 - Page not found
Sorry, the page you were looking for was not found.` for every single name.

Answer (score 5):

There is no limit on the length of URLs with libcurl or PHP cURL. So this is a non-issue.

What leads you to believe that there are size limits?

Comment: he's simply afraid of curl's power ;-)